# Angular 2, function inside *ngFor calling multiple time

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an array. to rendering that array i am using *ngFor inside for loop i am calculating some value using function but some how my function calling multiple time. Any one know why this kind of behaviour happening?

Comment: Please show us your code, we should then have a better understanding. We cannot help with this question with no code.

Comment: Please provide some code, it's hard to say without any example. 

You might be mixing up two things here. *ngFor (as mentioned in your post) is a structural directie which you use in your template. That's not the typical way to call methods inside your template. Maybe you mean a for loop in your controller?
Either way, both ways define an iteration through something (i.e. a collection), so if you have a method inside of your iteration, it's normal that it's being called multiple times.

Comment: Post code so it might help to understand what's happening.

Comment: If it's not a dupe, holler.